# Flask SqlAlchemy and Migrate Creating tables always but not detecting the updates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm making second revision of changing the table structure adding new tables and columns, but flask sqlalchemy on migrate is creating all the tables again.

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'old_table'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'new_table'
```

expected behavior was old table should not be added again..
**init**.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate


db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def creat_app():
   ...
   db.init_app(app)
   migrate.init_app(app, db)
```

models.py

```
from package_name import db

class MetaFields(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class Model1(MetaFields):
    __tablename__ = "new_table"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "schema_name"}
```

Comment: You are using schemas, yes? Did you enable the `include_schemas` option of Alembic? See for example https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/253

Comment: thanks.. it worked after adding include_schemas

Answer (score 0):

Got the migration working on flask db migrate to generate proper alembic patch on model changes.

Added below code in alembic env.py script:

```
schema = 'example'

def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == "table" and object.schema != schema:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

And updated `include_schemas` and `include_object` in the configuration script:

```
context.configure(
            ...
            include_schemas=True,
            include_object=include_object,
            ...
        )
```